# What is the best language to use for making API orders?

Tags: exchanges, api, trading, exchange-software

I have heard that python is at a disadvantage when it comes to making API requests. It’s built on C which makes it slower. Are there any languages that are low level enough to make fast requests and still API accessible?

Comment: You will very rarely find that the choice of language  is a major bottleneck,

Comment: I'd suggest Golang, it's fast enough and is designed API and website hosting. C is too low level, and C++ might still be a little low level.

Comment: C is not a slow language. C and its derivative C++ have become dominant because they are fast. C is fast enough that I have heard it called a "glorified assembler'.  I don't believe any python implementation is written in native machine language .  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717660/what-exactly-is-the-python-interpreter-implemented-with )

Answer (score -1):

Go - easy concurrency, productive and effcient